# AWK count occurence with zero

Tags: awk

I'm trying to count occurencies for matched strings in the column, but want to have "0" when there is no match:

column:

```
stringone
stringone
stringtwo
```

and result for matches with "stringone", "stringtwo", "stringthree" must be:

```
stringone 2
stringtwo 1
stringthree 0
```

I am able to get first two with this, bud don't know how to return "0":

```
awk 'match($1,/stringone|stringtwo|stringthree/,b){a[b[0]]++}END{for(i in a)print i ,a[i]}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the order is not important

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]; next} 
              {for(k in s) s[k]+=$0~k} 
           END{for(k in s) print k, s[k]}' search_terms file

stringone 2
stringthree 0
stringtwo 1
```

to provide the search terms as arguments

```
$ awk -v search='stringone|stringtwo|stringthree' \
    'BEGIN{n=split(search,st,"|")} 
          {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[i]+=$0~st[i]} 
     END  {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print st[i],c[i]}' file

stringone 2
stringtwo 1
stringthree 0
```

or perhaps

```
$ for s in string{one,two,three}; do echo -n "$s "; grep -c "$s" file; done

stringone 2
stringtwo 1
stringthree 0
```

Comment: looks nice, how can specify search terms directly instead of filename?

Answer (score 2):

This has the disadvantage of using a string instead of regex literal in the match. If you need to squeeze out every bit of performance you can duplicate the values in a regex literal, but then you have to be very careful to keep them synchronized.

```
BEGIN { re = "stringone|stringtwo|stringthree" }

match($1, re, b) { a[b[0]]++ }

END {
    for (i in a) {
        print i, a[i]
    }

    split(re, s, "|")
    for (i in s) {
        if (!(s[i] in a)) {
            print s[i], 0
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file
stringtwo 1
stringone 2
stringthree 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `file1` (like above) and search-words in `file2` in desired output order:

```
$ cat file2
stringone
stringtwo
stringthree
```

you could:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{print $1,a[$1]+0}' file1 file2
stringone 2
stringtwo 1
stringthree 0
```